# How to run ARM Android apps smoothly in x86 Unix-like OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, android, arm

I also mean AMD64, x86_64 and i386 PCs by saying x86.
Many common apps only support Android and iOS. That may cause inconvenience to Linux users. I wonder if there is any way to run ARM Android apps smoothly in Linux.
I tried Android Studio's ARM AVD. But it couldn't boot.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714482/android-studio-arm64-avd-not-supported-by-qemu2-on-linux-x86-64

Genymotion is claimed to support ARM. I installed a translation module in a Genymotion virtual device. But all the ARM apps I tested collapsed.
I heard that there's a "translation feature" in Android Studio's x86 AVD. But I didn't find any way to enable it.
Intel's 'houdini' seems to be a proprietary software so there might not be any way to get it.
There should be ways. Because many emulators in x86 Windows (eg. Bluestack) can run ARM software, although they're designed mainly for games.
I supposed a prossible way through QEMU (for example in Arch Linux):

1. install `qemu-common`,`qemu-desktop`,`qemu-system-arm`,`qemu-img`
2. `$ qemu-img create -f raw AndroidARM.img 30G`
3. `$ qemu-system-arm -cdrom AndroidARM.iso -boot order=d -accel kvm -drive file=AndroidARM.img`
   I haven't tested yet. But there are uncertainties. For example: Can I use KVM? Is the full-system emulation fast enough? Which ARM image use I use?

Comment: Android x86 works fine in my experience. Most apps have x86-64 binaries, so they work as well. Of course there are ARM only apps, and I've no idea what to do in this case.